# Django-RestFramework 2 and backbone.js routing

Tags: django, backbone.js, django-rest-framework

I am terribly confused about the routing and url set up when using backbone.js and django together with the Django-restframework.

1. Where does the the template fit in when using a REST framework?

For example, i have a class based view defined for one of my urls where i want to use backbone.js to just update the `div` displaying students:

```
url(r'^home/students/$', views.StudentList.as_view()),

class StudentList(APIView):
    """
    List all students
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        students = Person.objects.filter(person_type = Person.STUDENT)
        serializer = PersonSerializer(students)
        return Response(serializer.data, "core/teachers/teacher_teaching.html")

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
```

- How does Backbone routes fit in with the url routing of django. I have in a file router.js, something like this:

  ```
  function($,jqueryui, _, Backbone, HomeView, StudentsView) {

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
          // Define some URL routes
          ':home': 'showStudents',
          'users': 'showContributors',

          // Default
          '*actions': 'defaultAction'
      }
  });

  var initialize = function(){

      var app_router = new AppRouter;

      app_router.on('route:showStudents', function(){

          // Call render on the module we loaded in via the dependency array
          var studentsView = new StudentsView();
          studentsView.render();
      });
  ```

Yet the routes never actually get to my views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > Where does the the template fit in when using a REST framework?

It doesn't; Django templates are for normal Django HTML pages, not REST framework APIs.  REST framework API responses are programmatically-generated documents (typically JSON or XML), so they don't need templates.

> > How does Backbone routes fit in with the url routing of django

They are 100% completely separate.  Let's say you have a URL like:

```
www.example.com/foo/bar#baz
```

Django will handle this much of that URL:

```
www.example.com/foo/bar
```

while Backbone will handle the remaining:

```
#baz
```

Of course, that assumes that Django returns a webpage that uses Backbone; if it doesn't, the `#baz` will never even come in to play.

As a quick summary, when you visit a URL like the above, your browser will ask `www.example.com/` for `/foo/bar`.  This is when your `urls.py` in Django comes in; it has:

```
url(r'^foo/bar/?$', views.FooBar.as_view()),
```

so your webserver knows to send back whatever `views.FooBar.as_view()` gives it (whether that is REST framework-produced JSON document or an old school Django HTML document).

Once that document comes back to the server, it renders it, and this is where client-side code like Backbone and its router take their turn.  The Backbone Router (whenever you call `Backbone.history.start()`) looks at the URL (ie. `window.location`) and looks for the anchor or  "hash" part of the URL (eg. `#baz`).  It then compares that part of the URL to its route list (similar to how your webserver compared the earlier part to urls.py) and if it finds a match, it "sends you to a page".

It's key to understand though, it doesn't really send you anywhere at all; all its really doing is changing the hash part of the URL and then running some Javascript which manipulates the DOM.  Therefore, it is impossible for the Backbone Router to ever send you to a Django URL; if you want to hit a server route, you need to either use AJAX or `window.location =`.

Comment: +1 for the great explanation on routing. Just one last question about what you mentioned. Is backbone.js routing needed at all if django takes care of routing to my html page.

Comment: @Warz: if that page has multiple sections, tabs or subpages that should look like real separate pages and you want them to be accessible from the browser's navigation bar then yes.

Comment: Okay, so if my page with (tabs, subpages ...) all have proper {% url %} definitions, wouldn't they never have the hash tag '#' in front of them and thus backbone never reads the route. I really just want to be able to recognize the current url in both django and backbone, where django will serve the main template and backbone can make api calls and update using ajax certain pieces of the page?

Comment: "I really just want to be able to recognize the current url in both django and backbone" - What do you mean by "recognize"?  Only the server can build the document that gets to the client, and only the client can modify that document via JS, so it really doesn't matter what either one can "recognize", they both can only affect their spheres.

Comment: @machineghost By 'recognize', i meant routing to the correct view in backbone.js. I didn't understand that i had to pass a 'url' parameter to the model or collection. Within my router.js file, i am looking for something like 'users/' which was never matched even though i had a url mapping for it on the server side

Comment: You're not understanding: backbone can make a route for `www.example.com/#users/`; but it can't make a route for `www.example.com/users` (nor can ANY JS code).  Anything in the URL before the `#` goes to the server, the server decides what to do with it (in a Django application, it does this based on `urls.py`), then the server returns whatever page it wants.  AFTER that, Backbone gets a turn, and it can then render any view you want.  The key thing to understand is, the part before the `#` is for the server (`urls.py`), the part after is for the client (ie. `Backbone.Router`).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the patience here. I am just so used to the traditional server side routing and finding my way through backbone. How does the client side then add the '#' part of the url to execute certain parts of my javascript. I would like to coordinate between which view i am displaying in django and the javascript view that gets executed.

Comment: So, the order is: 1) you request someUrl from the server 2) server sends back a page (likely built from a Django template, 3) page loads its Javascript, including the Backbone Router, 4) Backbone Router checks what URL you're currently on, and then "routes" you to the appropriate view. Given that, if you want the user to go to "django view foo" and "backbone route bar", you need to give them a link with both parts in the URL, eg. example.com/foo#bar. However, let's say the user goes to example.com/foo, and you want them to then go to Backbone route "bar". What you have to do is ...

Comment: ... have the server "tell the client" to route to "bar" once the page loads. As I said, the router normally routes based on the URL, but you can also "manually" tell it to route via the navigate method of the router. To "tell the client" to do that, just add code at the bottom of the page that gets returned from Django: <script>yourRouter.navigate('bar')</script>. You could also get more complex, by having a var startingRoute = 'bar'` variable, then having your routing code check the starting route and navigate to it, but hopefully you can figure out what you want to do from there.

Comment: I see, so if i started at /foo and for example, i always want a user in a group 'admins' to get specific items in a 'ul' list, i could on the server side (with django hopefully, as i have access to the request.user object) add #admins, grab that ul tag and get my json data and append the template to that list item?

Comment: I couldn't quite follow your last comment, but it sounds like it's  outside the scope of this question.  I've explained the difference between Django/server-based and Backbone/client-based routing as well as I'm going to be able at this point, but if you have further questions I'd recommend starting a new Stack Overflow post for them.